# Forbid use of specific commands

Tags: shell-script, security, command, function, cluster

I develop tools on a cluster. Each user loads common environment files in their `.bash_profile`. I have a login node on which certain tools should not run. How can I prevent users from using those tools from specific nodes?

So far I have thought of redefining the tools' command in a function that would override the original tool:

```
$ tool  # Launches the tool normally.

$ vim common-env.sh  # Is sourced in each user's .bash_profile
function tool() {
  if [ $(is_in_forbiden_node) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You have to leave node X before launching this command!"
    return 1  # Forbids the use of the original tool.
  else 
     command tool  # Launches the original tool normally.
  fi
}
export -f tool
```

This works, however this is far from being flawless. The user can still circumvent this limitation by typing the following:

```
$ command tool
```

or :

```
$ /usr/bin/env tool
```

What are the alternatives?
Please note that I am no system administrator so any actions requiring admin privileges won't benefit me.

Comment: since users have control over their own `.bash_profile` they can simply not source the `common-env.sh` to circumvent you. There wont be environment variables that you can set to avoid the users executing the tools. They have to be unable to run them, or for the tool to run but behave differently (such as exit) on certain nodes.

Comment: Are you saying that you can change the environment of other users (edit a file sourced by other users on login) without being administrator?!

Comment: "Please note that I am no system administrator so any actions requiring admin privileges won't benefit me."

Well this is a job for a system administrator so either you were improperly given this task or you are an system administrator.

Comment: @ Daniel Margosian: heh you are right.
@ Stéphane Chazelas: Fortunately no I don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new group, give the executable such new group, and remove executable bit (and also read permission) to that executable.

This is a common method for "games" programs, but i think it is veyry similar to that you are looking.

Comment: Alas creating a group requires administrator's privileges.

Comment: @user3298319 Are all users currently a part of the same group? If so then you'll either need a new user group, or place this error checking in the tools themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Without administrative power the only place that is left is `tool` itself.  In particular, you need `tool` to check whether it runs on a permitted node or not.

You need to be careful on how you perform this check. For instance, environment variables are not trustworthy. Moreover, wrappers like shell scripts that do the checking and launch the tool if permissible won't work either as a user may invoke the actual tool in the first place.